# NextJS Apollo Client Error Cannot read property '__APOLLO_STATE__' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo

Why am I getting Cannot read property '**APOLLO_STATE**' of undefined from my Apollo client? I got the client from the nextjs example repository on github:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib

Comment: are you wrapping your App with apollo provider?

Comment: @Sodhisaab yes i have done that

Comment: While providing a link is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.